# routes / after_sign_in_path_for not working on Production (Rails 5.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I just updated my app to redirect a user after signing in based on their user role.

For example if the user.role == "admin" it should take it to the admin_root_path...

and if user.role == "customer" it should take it to portal_root_path.

For some reason it works on DEVELOPMENT, but when I tested on PRODUCTION it gave me an error trying to redirect to the admin_root_path all the time, I was signing in with a "customer" user. This is the error on the PRODUCTION server.

```
Processing by AdminController#index as HTML Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

(FYI) the root_path for the application is still root to: "admin#index", with an before_action :authenticate_user! on the application controller...

This is where I created the root paths on my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "admin/index"

  scope :portal, as: 'portal' do
    root to: "portal#index"
  end

  scope :admin, as: 'admin' do
    root to: "admin#index"
  end

  root to: "admin#index"
end
```

This is my application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception, prepend: true
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.role == "admin"
      admin_root_path
    elsif resource.role == "customer"
      portal_root_path
    else
      super
    end
  end

  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  private

  def user_not_authorized
    flash[:alert] = "You are not authorized to perform this action."
    redirect_to(request.referrer || portal_root_path)
  end
end
```

Any recommendations? Any idea why it behaves differently on DEV and PRODUCTION environments?

-- EDIT
This is my PortalController, the view uses the variable @customer to display Customer's information.

```
class PortalController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_customer

def index
end

private

# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_customer
  @customer = Customer.friendly.find(current_user.customer_id)
end
```

end

Thanks so much!

Comment: I think, `root` is handled by default, and since you're saying `root to: admin#index` at the end, it is overriding all of the above routes. This is just my guess, I have never defined routes this way though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and change your routes to look like this ?

```
scope :portal do
  resources :portals, only: :index
  // if you don't want to use resources, just define a static route
end

scope :admin do
  resources :admins, only: :index
  // if you don't want to use resources, just define a static route
end
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I tested again on Production (it works on Development) and it seems that the after_sign_in_path is working properly since it directs to Admin (if user is admin) and to /portal (if user is Customer) The admin routes work properly, but the portal index breaks on Production... (The page you were looking for does not exist)... I don't understand why since I have both controllers and index pages structured the same way. I will run a production environment locally to see if I can get better logs...

Comment: So far I am thinking that it has to do with my PortalController that as a function set_customer, that might act differently on Production. The function is: 

  def set_customer
    @customer = Customer.friendly.find(current_user.customer_id)
  end

Comment: I just added the PortalController on the original post (edit)... Thanks!